cannot query azure search ai endpoint
I am using the below to authentication into azure search:
cred = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = cred.get_token(api)
params = {'api-version': os.environ['AZURE_SEARCH_API_VERSION']}
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}','Content-Type': 'application/json'}

search_payload = {
        "search": QUESTION, # Text query
        "select": "id, title, name, location, chunk",
        "queryType": "semantic",
        "vectorQueries": [{"text": QUESTION, "fields": "chunkVector", "kind": "text", "k": k}], # Vector query
        "semanticConfiguration": "my-semantic-config",
        "captions": "extractive",
        "answers": "extractive",
        "count":"true",
        "top": k
    }

r = requests.post(os.environ['AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT'] + "/indexes/" + index + "/docs/search",
                     data=json.dumps(search_payload), headers=headers, params=params)

however i get a 401 error code when i print status code of r.
note: i have permissions of "Search Index Data Reader" and the app has an identity.
what else could be causing this issue?

Could you decode the token in jwt.ms and check what aud it's having? What scope you used to get token?

the aud matches the api for the search when i put it in jwt.ms

when you say what scope to get the token what do you mean?

What value you are passing in api of this line token = cred.get_token(api)?

"https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default"

Try using https://search.azure.com/.default

The error occurred as you are using wrong scope while generating token to call Azure AI Search endpoint.
I have one Azure Search service where I enabled API Access control as Both as below:

Now, I added "Search Index Data Reader" role to my user under the Search service like this:

But when I tried to call the Search endpoint query with api value as https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default, I too got response code as 401 :


To resolve the error, you need to use https://search.azure.com/.default as  api value to generate token for Azure AI Search endpoint.

When I ran below code by making above change, I got the response successfully like this:
import os
import json
import requests
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

api_version = "2020-06-30" 
index = "hotels-sample-index"

search_endpoint = "https://demosearch0904.search.windows.net"

k = 10 
QUESTION = "luxury" 
api = "https://search.azure.com/.default"

cred = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = cred.get_token(api)

params = {'api-version': api_version}
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token.token}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

search_payload = {
    "search": QUESTION,
    "select": "*",  
    "count": "true",
    "top": k
}

r = requests.post(f"{search_endpoint}/indexes/{index}/docs/search",
                  data=json.dumps(search_payload), headers=headers, params=params)

if r.status_code == 200:
    search_results = r.json()
    print(search_results)
else:
    print(f"Error: {r.status_code} - {r.text}")

Response:

